# How to extract lines knowing start and end lines

Tags: sed, cat, tail, head

I have a file with 1 million lines.
I want to extract lines from line 10001 to 500000 
How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sed` is your friend:

```
sed -n '10001,500000p;500001q'
```

Note that 500001q is needed to stop further file processing. Otherwise it will still read the file till the very end. Thanks for hint on this to @Freddy.

Comment: Maybe add `;500001q` to stop further processing.

Comment: Updated the answer. Thx for hint

Answer (score 1):

Might as well have a `head`/`tail` solution as well:

```
head -n 500000 yourfile.txt | tail -n +10001
```

(Somewhat misleadingly, `tail -n +10` is different from `tail -n 10` – the former starts at line 10, the latter only prints the last 10 lines.)